# Autoposition legend to dodge plotted data in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is there any way to position a legend *inside* the plot area while minimizing its overlap with data points? I realize that `legend.position` can be tuned manually, and that the package `ggrepel` handles similar behavior for text labels, but I'm looking for an existing/new programmatic method to put the legend in a non-busy location of the plot.

I'd like to use it with plots made using `ggplot2`, although a general solution would also be welcome.

Comment: you'll need to create the fonction